# Tkinter Button Widget Error: Expected Integer but Got String 'Nerd'

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, button

I'm encountering an error while trying to add a button widget to a Tkinter window in Python. Drawing a window to the screen works fine though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/saif/new/c.py", line 11, in <module>
      button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=button_clicked)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2679, in __init__
      Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
      self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "Nerd"
```

Here's the source code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a function to be called when the button is clicked
def button_clicked():
    print("Button clicked!")

# Create a button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=button_clicked)
button.pack()

# Run the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

General Overview:

```
Python 3.10.12
tk                     0.1.0
tk-tools               0.16.0
Linux Mint 21.1 (Xorg)
```

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: The error message says that the button is on line 11, but in your posted code it is on line 14.  This is not your real code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have edited the new lines after each comments. Check now.

Comment: There's no possible way that the code you posted, run with the standard Tkinter library, could produce this error - the string `"Nerd"` does not exist in the code, nor does any sort of obfuscated expression that could produce that string.  So either this *isn't* actually the code you're running, or somebody has modified your Tkinter library (possibly as a prank).  I would suggest searching the /usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py file for `Nerd`;  perhaps there is other text nearby that would indicate who did this to you, and why?

Comment: This is my personal laptop and no one could possibly do that. I installed customtkinter using. Both has the same problem.

Here's 2589-2609 of that `/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py` file:
```python3
    def __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf={}, kw={}, extra=()):
.
.
.
                self.tk.call(
            (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
.
.
.
```

`"Nerd"` I am guessing could be calling out some variable here. The only thing I can imagine is my default `JetBrains Nerd Fonts`

Comment: Don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. Also comments don't always appear in chronological order. [Edit] your question instead.